# WebStorm File Watcher is not working, access denied

Tags: sass, webstorm, file-watcher

When trying to compile a project, the File Watcher breaks down to compile .sass files into .css via WebStorm. The error message looks like this:

> The watcher has been disabled. Error: Cannot run program
> "/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/lib/node_modules/sass" (in
> directory "/home/admin/WebstormProjects/test-project/css"): error=13,
> Permission denied

I have already granted privileges to folders (for example, read-write-execute), but this did not help me figure out the problem. Thank you in advance for your help!

BTW, sass is installed globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by specifying the path to sass.js file instead of the sass directory in FileWatcher.